# Landscape layout in portrait orientation android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-orientation

I want to show landscape xml into portrait mode. Below is sample:

[image]

i have tried making layout-land folder and adding xml into and attaching it to portrait activity but this is not working.

Please help me with some ideas or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to force your Activity to show always in landscape mode in your `Manifest.xml` file:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.loading.LoadingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: and should i use tablayout or gridlayout for this kind of table view?

Comment: I think you should to use a TableLayout because in this case you will have more control of your cells.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, Just add

```
android:rotation = "90"
```

to your XML Layout
which will help you Just display like Landscape in portrait orientation

OR
Even you can do it same from the Java:

```
yourLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
yourLayout.setRotation(90.0f);
```

you need at-least API level 11 to use rotation